# angular js table based on spreadsheet type data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have been struggling with this for a while using Angular. Extensive research has not helped

I am trying to replicate a spreadsheet style data in a HTML using ng-repeat.
This is my desired output

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Account</th>
    <th>Jan</th> 
    <th>Feb</th>
    <th>Mar</th>
    <th>Apr</th>
    <th>May</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Sales</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>150</td>
    <td>250</td>
    <td>350</td>
    <td>450</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Variable Costs</td>
    <td>150</td>
    <td>250</td>
    <td>150</td>
    <td>150</td>
    <td>250</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

There are 3 essential elements for which I trying to build a table.

I can build the columns using ng-repeat no problem.

My Json looks like this

```
["Jan",
"Feb",
"Mar",
"Apr",
"May",
"Jun",
"Jul",
"Aug",
"Sep",
"Oct",
"Nov",
"Dec"]
```

and my Angular looks like this
      
        
                Account Description
        
          
            {{value }}

I **can** also build the Rows with a Json

["Sales", "Variable Costs", "Advertising"]

```
      <tr ng-repeat="(header, value) in tm1rows" >
        <td> {{value }} 
    </td>
```

Where I am struggling is to display the value in the table for the Month where for a particular Account and Month combination.

I have a json which looks like this.

```
[{
        "account2": "Sales",
        "month": "Jan",
        "TM1CubeValue": 9090
    },
    {
        "account2": "Variable Costs",
        "month": "Jan",
        "TM1CubeValue": null
    },
    {
        "account2": "Sales",
        "month": "Feb",
        "TM1CubeValue": null
    },
    {
        "account2": "Sales",
        "month": "Feb",
        "TM1CubeValue": 1999
    },
    {
        "account2": "Variable Costs",
        "month": "Feb",
        "TM1CubeValue": 99
    }
]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I have given enough detail but I can provide more if need be.

Cheerio

Comment: Looking at your desired output, how would you be able to have a single value in each row 'Sales' and 'Variable Costs' if you have multiple of the same type in your JSON data, for example in Feb you have two for 'Sales' TM1CubeValue's 1999 and null? How do you want to handle this?

Comment: Sorry the json result is something like this, 
[{
        "account2": "Sales",
        "month": "Jan",
        "TM1CubeValue": 9090
    },
    {
        "account2": "Variable Costs",
        "month": "Jan",
        "TM1CubeValue": null
    },
    {
        "account2": "Sales",
        "month": "Feb",
        "TM1CubeValue": 1999
    },
    {
        "account2": "Variable Costs",
        "month": "Feb",
        "TM1CubeValue": 99
    }
]

Answer (score 0):

Using your amended data as shown in the question comments. You should use **ng-repeat** and **filters** to populate the table and filter out depending on your 'account2' type in your th and td elements as shown:

```
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Account</th>
        <th ng-repeat="i in months">{{i}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Sales</td>
        <td ng-repeat="i in tableData | filter : {'account2' : 'Sales'}">{{i.TM1CubeValue}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Variable Costs</td>
        <td ng-repeat="i in tableData  | filter : {'account2' : 'Variable Costs'}">{{i.TM1CubeValue}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

You will need to put your months array and actual data in **$scope** variables.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.months = ["Jan",
    "Feb",
    "Mar",
    "Apr"];

  $scope.tableData = [{
    "account2": "Sales",
    "month": "Jan",
    "TM1CubeValue": 9090
  }, {
    "account2": "Variable Costs",
    "month": "Jan",
    "TM1CubeValue": null
  }];
});
```

I have provided a working example in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yTWUspAzRaTXyQf9y0PW).